# Python Multiprocessing Pool - dictionary arguments not working

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Below code executing without any errors, but when i call the values of the dictionary(`dict_of_queries`) which is actually a simple `SQL statements` from `apply_async()` , the queries are not executing..

I tried `map()`, `starmap()` - but still queries are not executing..

CODE:

```
dict_of_queries={'D': 'UPDATE D SET ROW2=100', 'E':'UPDATE E SET ROW2=100'}

def fn(value):
   #establish connection to database
   cur.execute(value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   
    p = Pool(processes=2)
    for key,value in dict_of_queries.items():
        p.apply_async(fn, args=(value, ))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Comment: database may need `conn.commit()` to execute `UPDATE` query.

Answer (score 0):

I find the ProcessPoolExecutor (from concurrent.futures) easier to use. Here's a processing pattern that you could adapt for your needs:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import sqlite3

DB = 'my.db' # path to your database

def fn(sql):
    try:
        with sqlite3.connect(DB) as db:
            db.cursor().execute(sql)
            db.commit()
    except sqlite3.OperationalError as e:
        print(e)


dict_of_queries={'D': 'UPDATE D SET ROW2=100', 'E':'UPDATE E SET ROW2=100'}

def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for future in [executor.submit(fn, v) for v in dict_of_queries.values()]:
            future.result() # wait for subprocess to complete

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

EDIT: Rewritten to demonstrate how this could work with sqlite3

Comment: Thanks, But is this multithreading ?.. 

 i specifically need to do multiprocessing, i have hundreds of SQL statements in a table and i loop through the SQL statements and execute that and complete as fast as possible. so multiprocessing with 4 processes help me to execute all the SQL statements quickly.

Comment: This is multiprocessing. The clue is in the name - ProcessPoolExecutor. [This](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) will help you

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer utilises ProcessPoolExecutor. This question doesn't really justify that level of complexity, so here's something much simpler. Once again assuming that the underlying database is sqlite3. Adaptation for other databases should be trivial.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import sqlite3
    
DB = 'my.db' # path to your database
    
def fn(sql):
    try:
        with sqlite3.connect(DB) as db:
            db.cursor().execute(sql)
            db.commit()
    except sqlite3.OperationalError as e:
        print(e)

    
dict_of_queries={'D': 'UPDATE D SET ROW2=100', 'E':'UPDATE E SET ROW2=100'}
    
def main():
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(fn, dict_of_queries.values())
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```